# How to parse a csv file which has some field containing seprator (comma) as-values

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

sample message - 111,222,333,444,555,val1in6th,val2in6th,777

The sixth column contains a value consisting of commas (val1in6th,val2in6th is a sample value of 6th column).
When I use a simple csv filter this message is getting converted to 8 fields. I want to be able to tell the filter that val1in6th,val2in6th should be treated as a single value and placed as the value of 6th column (its okay not to have comma between val1in6th and val2in6th when placed as the output as 6th column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your plugin, no more the csv one but `grok filter` - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).
Then you use a debugger to create a parser for your lines - like this one: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

For your lines you could use this grok expression:

```
%{WORD:FIELD1},%{WORD:FIELD2},%{WORD:FIELD3},%{WORD:FIELD4},%{WORD:FIELD5},%{GREEDYDATA:FIELD6}
```

or :

```
%{INT:FIELD1},%{INT:FIELD2},%{INT:FIELD3},%{INT:FIELD4},%{INT:FIELD5},%{GREEDYDATA:FIELD6}
```

It changes the datatypes in elastic of the firsts 5 fields.

To know about parse csv with grok filter in elastic you could use this  [es official blog guide](https://www.elastic.co/blog/indexing-csv-elasticsearch-ingest-node), it is explained how to use grok with ingestion pipeline, but it is the same with logstash

Comment: Thanks for your response. It would have been okay to use this approach had it contained only 6 columns. How do I add the 7th column?

Comment: in the same way: %{INT:FIELD1},%{INT:FIELD2},%{INT:FIELD3},%{INT:FIELD4},%{INT:FIELD5},%{GREEDYDATA:FIELD6},%{INT:FIELD7}

Comment: you could check your parser using a grok debugger, like the one mentioned in my answer

Comment: GREEDYDATA has to be the last field. Greedydata will just take everything and put into FIELD6. 

So att %{INT:FIELD6},%{INT:FIELD}...%{GREEDYDATA:rest_of_fields}

Comment: @opentokix Not necessarily. you can check it from the grok debugger. From logstash documentation GREEDYDATA represents .* https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Comment: @Lupanoide And when does .* not take "the rest"?

Comment: when the .* expression in on parenthesys . Have you even tried GREEDYDATA or not?

Comment: @opentokix did you know what groups in regex are and what is their relationship with grok patterns?